# Amazon aws could not found .pom while cordova plugin integration

Tags: android, cordova, amazon-web-services, gradle, cordova-plugins

Hello I am new in Cordova application development.

I have developed one Cordova plugin in that plugin I used one native Android local .aar library developed in kotlin.

Next, I want to use that plugin in another Cordova application. That Cordova application is using amazon ws. In that application plugin is added successfully but Cordova app not building producing following error.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:

Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.

> Could not resolve :cuckooApp:.

  Required by:

      project :app

   > Could not resolve :cuckooApp:.

      > Could not get resource 'https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/jp-build-packages/ec-android-sdk//cuckooApp//cuckooApp-.pom'.

         > Could not GET 'https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/jp-build-packages/ec-android-sdk//cuckooApp//cuckooApp-.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
```

Comment: Did you setup your aws credentials ?

Comment: Yes. Aws library checking for a .pom file on maven but I didn't publish library on maven I am using it locally. And local library it should not check for .pom file on maven. But it aws checking I don't know why @ToYonos

Comment: Could you share the relevant part of your build file(s) ?

Comment: which build file I have to share Cordova App or Cordova plugin? @ToYonos

Comment: Both I guess :-)